# Discord Bot Status not automaticaly changing

Tags: discord.py

i am programming a Discord bot at the moment and I have the problem that if i have tabby open everything works fine, but if i close tabby everything still works except the status don't change anymore.

Thanks for your help!
Niklas

Here is my code:

```
@bot.event
async def precence():
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=f"{len(bot.guilds)} server"))
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=f"{len(bot.users)} users"))
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="!help"))
    await asyncio.sleep(5)

bot.loop.create_task(precence())
```

I din't try anything because i don't know what i should do.

Comment: Dont do `@bot.event` this isnt a event. Also, try using the tasks extension (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html). Also the function is only running once

Comment: Thanks, i tried it and now its working.

Comment: Mind if I add an answer to mark it? So other users see it more easier?